# Converting from select to check list?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a select list like such:

```
<select name="taxonomy[1][]" multiple="multiple" class="form-select" id="edit-taxonomy-1" size="7">
<option value="13">Glaciers</option>
<option value="14">Lake Ice</option>
<option value="17">Permafrost</option>
<option value="16">River Ice</option>
<option value="15">Sea Ice</option>
<option value="12">Snow</option>
</select>
```

This list is being dynamically created and I'm not sure how to change the output display. I have seen tutorials like this: http://www.netvivs.com/convert-regular-select-into-a-drop-down-checkbox-list-using-jquery/ which convert a select into a dropdown check list. Is there a way using php,javascript,jquery, to convert the select to display as a checklist? Preferably in table form so I get 2 rows with 3 columns?

Comment: change the html with that to checkboxes?

Comment: not change the html. change the display

Comment: Use the link you reference in your question. Are you looking for someone to write the code?

Comment: @cdburgess no I'm looking for someone to start me off or reference me to a library that does something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in a custom way like so:

```
$('#edit-taxonomy-1').parent().append('<table id="checkboxes"><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>');

$('#edit-taxonomy-1 option').each(function() {
var label = $(this).html();
var value = $(this).attr('value');
$('#checkboxes tbody tr').append('<td><input type="checkbox" value="'+value+'">'+label+'</td>');
});
```

Or just use the plugin: http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/

Comment: this didn't work the first time and I tried it again and it worked cooool

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the example link does it using jquery...

Just make sure you have a source to jquery.js library, as well as a source to the library that site has offered as a download.

Then just call,

```
$("#edit-taxonomy-1").dropdownchecklist();
```

I havent tried it, but thats what the tutorial says to do...

Good luck.

PS - I had a hard time trying to find the download of the actual library from that site, so here it is. http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/

Comment: I'd like the checkboxes without the dropdown though

Comment: Ahh I see. Can you not set an attribute / use javascript to keep the drop down open?

Comment: I'm not very good with javascript and just don't really know how to do that